# Hive CLI giving problem while starting it

Tags: hive

When i run command hive it is only able to start from bin folder beacause metastore is created in bin only if i run it from home its not able to get start and shows error.
   I have added these lines in my **.bashrc** file for hive
   HIVE **env** variables

```
export HIVE_HOME=/opt/hadoop/hive/apache-hive-2.3.4-bin
export PATH=$HIVE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to setup path as mentioned below and retry,

```
user@ubuntu:~$  sudo gedit  ~/.bashrc
```

Copy and paste the following lines at end of the file

```
# Set HIVE_HOME
export HIVE_HOME="/opt/hadoop/hive/apache-hive-2.3.4-bin" 
PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

But here my suggestion is, instead of using hive command prompt try to use recommended way that is beeline client. If you have hiveserver2 configured you can connect using beeline client and query to hive.